# c# .net memory mapped files across machines

Tags: c#, .net, shared-memory, interprocess

I was wondering if it is possible to access a memory mapped file (c#, .net) from a foreign machine? My instinct tells me "no" but I want to make sure.

I'm looking for an IPC mechanism that is guaranteed to only function on the same computer. WCF for instance can be configured to go off machine and we have a picky client that doesn't want to assume that risk.

Comment: The thought of directly exposing memory space to arbitrary remote requests is scary...

Comment: I'd have said WCF. Use a secure authentication header, over SSL.

Comment: are the machines on the same local network?

Comment: Conceivable there could be, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file part of a (persisted) MMF is just a file...

And although it usually will be properly locked and protected it is not totally unconceivable that that file is opened from another machine.

Not something I would normally consider a risk but if you're passing over WCF because it *could* be configured for network access...

But with a non-persisted MMF you should be safe.